# Many questions tagged "ide" should be tagged "pata"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Many of the questions currently tagged "ide" should actually be tagged "pata". [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) is for integrated development environments, rather than Integrated Drive Electronics.

Comment: Perhaps some future cases could be eliminated by making `ide-drive` a synonym of `pata` and so on.

Comment: The computer industry is known for many terminological conflicts, and I suspect this is likely to increase over time.  Take a look at the [tag:dos] tag at http://superuser.com/tags/dos/info which defines both DOS (Disk Operating System) and DoS (Denial of Service) on one page.  (_I also prefer @Matthew Read's suggestion to use an "ide-drive" tag; +1 for his comment._)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing questions which referred to [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) as a drive have been edited out, the synonym had already been created by [random](https://superuser.com/users/307/random)

[image: synonym to ide]