# Proposed resolution for [ide]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Every few years, we do a cleanup of [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) tags, for example:

- [Many questions tagged "ide" should be tagged "pata"](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3212/many-questions-tagged-ide-should-be-tagged-pata)
- [Old monthly tag cleanups](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/old-monthly-tag-cleanups)

Someone just anonymously cleaned up several PATA questions tagged [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) and I found and cleaned up 20-some more.  There are now 156 questions remaining, and those look properly tagged with [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide).

We have an [ide-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide-drive) tag as a [pata](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pata) synonym, but as long as we have the [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) tag, it will continue to get misused and create a cleanup requirement.  It has a wiki excerpt with guidance, which gets ignored.

I propose replacing the [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) tag with an unambiguous tag to permanently solve the problem.  As DavidPostill points out, fully spelling out `integrated-development-environment` won't fit in the 25 character limit, so some abbreviated form would be required.

Simply leaving out letters creates a misspelling problem for people trying to type the tag.  It is better to use common abbreviated forms of the words so that the tag is easy to remember and reasonably short to type.  An example would be [int-dev-env](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/int-dev-env).

The drawback is that new posters would not know the short form, and would have a tough time finding or guessing it.  So this is not a good solution.

An **alternative** that improves on the current situation but doesn't completely solve the problem:

- Make [ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) a synonym of an unambiguous tag that is what is attached to the question, for example: [integrated-dev-environ](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/integrated-dev-environ).  That gives users a quick, intuitive, and familiar route to the tag, but displays a tag that will obviously not apply to PATA.

  That may lead the OP who needs the [pata](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pata) tag to hover on the tag to see what's going on, which will yield guidance.  If not, the tag will be more obviously wrong to other users, who may fix it at posting time.

Comment: No automation. Even us mods do it by hand. Making a synonymn is fine but we'd probably want to start with a list first. and do a TCW type thing

Comment: Tag Cleanup Weekend ;p

Comment: Unfortunately `integrated-development-environment` is too long by 9 characters. Max tag length is 25.

Comment: @DavidPostill, good catch.  OK, Plan B.

Comment: @DavidPostill intergrated-dev-environment ?

Comment: Ah still too long, duuur.

Comment: @djsmiley2k And it's spelled wrongly :)